# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am instentiating $db object this way in my  database class

```
class MysqlDB {

    protected $_mysql;
    protected $_where = array();
    protected $_query;
    protected $_paramTypeList;
    protected $_crudType = null;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db) {
        $this->_mysql = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
    }


    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
        return $results;
    }
        protected function _prepareQuery()
    {
        echo $this->_query;
        if (!$stmt = $this->_mysql->prepare($this->_query)) {
            trigger_error("Problem preparing query", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $stmt;
    }

}
```

I am using this $db object in another class(profile class) as a link identifier  as

```
$db = new MysqlDb('localhost','root','','xxx');

$query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM categories_general");
```

How can I get rid of this error? Actually, I am recently shifted from MySQL to mysqli.

Comment: try `$db->query( "SELECT id, ..."); `

Comment: I recommend you use if you use mysqli object handling

Comment: @air4x now it says undefinec $db.

Comment: Object or process are you using?

Comment: Is `MysqlDb` a class you have created for database operations. If so show us your code for `MysqlDb`?

Comment: @air4x,I have edit the question.Plz review.

Comment: Show your `_prepareQuery()` function too

Comment: Have you included the file for `MysqlDB` in the class where you are using it ? Try `var_dump($db);` there and see if `$db` is accessible there.

Comment: @air4x,yes I am including it,now I have simplified my questuon with few edits

Answer (score 6):

try

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','XXX','XXX');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
$sql = "select * from user";
$result = $db->query($sql);
var_dump($result->fetch_assoc());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using procedural style of mysqli. So you must create query method in db class.

```
class db{
  private $connection;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->connect();
  }
  public function connect(){
    $this->connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','new5');
  }
  //add these methods
  public function query($query_string){
    return mysqli_query($this->connection, $query_string);
  }
  public function fetch_row($mysqli_result){
    return mysqli_fetch_row($this->connection, $mysqli_result);
  }
  //and other functions you need
}
```

or you can use object oriented style with extends method;

```
class db extends mysqli{
  function __construct($host, $username, $password, $databaseName, $port=3306){
    mysqli::__construct($host, $username, $password, $databaseName, $port);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a function

```
public function getDB()
{
    return $this->_mysql;
}

 $query=mysqli_query($db->getDB(),"SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM categories_general");
```