# How to connect to MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kinda new in PHP, but I was told to create a login form that connects to Mysql database.

I tried the following code to connect to the database, tried it with, and without the database. I tried mysql_connect and something else, but always got the same error: (hidden:servername and others are the proper information of the server, just it is not pulbic.)

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in
>   C:\Users\vg141fy\login\login.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\vg141fy\login\login.php on line 25

```
<?php
    if (ISSET($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $servername = "hidden:servername";
        $username = "hidden:username";
        $password = "hidden:password";
        $database = "hidden:database";

        $conn= mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    }
?>
```

I open a localhost to open my php pages with "php -S localhost:4000", but i don't use XAMPP. Should I use it, or is there something else that is miss?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? Because the first result I got was this one and it exactly describes your problem and the solution to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170672/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-in/13170690

Comment: Or use `new mysqli()`.

Comment: I tried, and not a single solution was the solution for me.. I keep getting the error @ArtvanScheppingen

Comment: With    new mysqli(),    i got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Users\vg141fy\login\login.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\vg141fy\login\login.php on line 25 @aynber

Comment: Make sure your PHP is combined with mysqli, which can be found by putting `<?php phpinfo();` into a file and checking the installed extensions. If it's not installed, you'll need to check how to install it for your version and OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [quick start guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

If you are using the OO interface, you need to include the `new` keyword.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

If you are using the procedural interface, then you need to use the `mysqli_connect` function.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check first that connection successfully established or not 
use this to connect your database using this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{
    echo "success";
}

?>
```

if it give success message then error should be in your after connection code so try to create table and check

Comment: `die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);` and when the connection fails for some reason "everybody" knows MySQL is used as database... [Information leak/disclosure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leak_(information_disclosure)) in juicy errors like your are using is in fact a application vulnerability

Comment: "kinda" is a new in PHP so i suggest to learn basic code to understand connection with database so i suggest this answer for him

Answer (score -1):

Try to change **database credential** below and ensure that it matches yours.

If the connection failed it will print error below **could not connect to database**.

```
  <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'your-db-username';
     $dbpass = 'your-db-pass';
     $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

     if(! $conn ){
        //die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    echo 'Could not connect to database ';
     }

     echo 'Connected successfully';
     mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```